# Size of struct within another struct in Matlab (R2010a 64-bit linux)

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm working with a Matlab API that loads data from a proprietary format into a series of structures. Here's an example of what a dataset looks like after loading a file:

> >>fieldnames(data(1))
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 'Grid_Point_ID'
> 'Grid_Point_Latitude'
> 'Grid_Point_Longitude'
> 'Grid_Point_Altitude'
> 'Grid_Point_Mask'
> 'BT_Data'
> ```
>
> >> data(1).BT_Data
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
> ```
>
> >> fieldnames(data(1).BT_Data(1))
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 'Flags'
> 'BT_Value_Real'
> 'BT_Value_Imag'
> 'Pixel_Radiometric_Accuracy'
> 'Incidence_Angle'
> 'Azimuth_Angle'
> 'Faraday_Rotation_Angle'
> 'Geometric_Rotation_Angle'
> 'Snapshot_ID_of_Pixel'
> 'Footprint_Axis1'
> 'Footprint_Axis2'
> ```

I want to loop over all `data(i).BT_Data(j)`. I've already got the length of `data` fine, but I can't get the size/length of `BT_Data` (which varies for each `data(i)`):

> >> length(data(1).BT_Data)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1
> ```
>
> >> size(data(1).BT_Data)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1     1
> ```

My expected result here is `ans = 66` (or equivalent array for `size()`).

I'm not terribly familiar with the structure data format, which may be part of my struggles. But `length(data)` worked fine, so I'm confused why it won't work on `BT_Data` (I've also tried `BT_Data(:)`).

The most relevant previous answer I can find is [1757250](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757250/matlab-determine-total-length-size-of-a-structure-array-with-fields-as-structure), but I couldn't get it to work (I think it doesn't apply here). Thanks for any insight you can provide.

`------` EDIT `------`

Here's a little more insight into how I have to use the API to even get to the point where I'm at:

> >> system('ln -sf /opt/rwapi-matlab/lib/rwapi/smos/config/xml_rw_api.usr_conf.xml .');
>   setenv('XML_RW_API_HOME','/opt/rwapi-matlab/lib/rwapi');
>   path(path,'/opt/rwapi-matlab');
>
> >> prod = RWAPI.product('SM_OPEB_MIR_SCLF1C_20110202T013659_20110202T014642_346_060_1')
>
> Array SMOS Matlab Interface version 1.4
>   (c) 2010 Array Systems Computing Inc. of Canada (http://www.array.ca)
>   Distribution or modification of this software requires written permission from Array
>
> prod =
>
> ```
> RWAPI.product handle
> Package: RWAPI
>
> Properties:
>      filename: 'SM_OPEB_MIR_SCLF1C_20110202T013659_20110202T014642_346_060_1'
>        header: [1x1 struct]
> xml_datablock: []
> ```
>
> Methods, Events, Superclasses
>
> >> data = prod.dataset(2)
>
> data =
>
> RWAPI.dataset handle with no properties.
>     Package: RWAPI
>
> Methods, Events, Superclasses
>
> >> data(1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>        Grid_Point_ID: 251721
>  Grid_Point_Latitude: 25.5000
> Grid_Point_Longitude: -102.2590
>  Grid_Point_Altitude: 1.4714e+03
>      Grid_Point_Mask: 2
>              BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
> ```
>
> >> data(1).BT_Data
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
> ```
>
> >> data(1).BT_Data(1)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>                      Flags: 6229
>              BT_Value_Real: 262.5275
>              BT_Value_Imag: 0
> Pixel_Radiometric_Accuracy: 6160
>            Incidence_Angle: 31966
>              Azimuth_Angle: 10299
>     Faraday_Rotation_Angle: 65277
>   Geometric_Rotation_Angle: 58605
>       Snapshot_ID_of_Pixel: 65752530
>            Footprint_Axis1: 19649
>            Footprint_Axis2: 14625
> ```
>
> >> whos
>   Name      Size               Bytes  Class            Attributes
>
> ans       1x1                    1  logical
>     data      1x19091              112  RWAPI.dataset
>     prod      1x2                  112  RWAPI.product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I really suspect it's an oddity in an overrridden subsref method in those RWAPI classes. I was able to reproduce all your observed behavior by defining a class with a slightly pathological subsref.

```
classdef stupidref
    %STUPIDREF Reproduce odd indexing behavior that jpatton saw. Buggy.
    properties
        BT_Data = repmat(struct('foo',42, 'bar',42), [1 66]);
    end
    methods
        function B = subsref(A,S)
            s = S(1);
            subs = s.subs;
            chain = S(2:end);

            switch s.type
                case '()'
                    B = builtin( 'subsref', A, s );
                    if ~isempty(chain)
                        B = subsref(B, chain);
                    end

                case '.'
                    % Non-standard behavior!
                    if ~isempty(chain) && isequal(chain(1).type, '()')
                        B = subsref(A.(s.subs), chain);
                    else
                        B = struct(s.subs, A.(s.subs));
                    end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is consistent with the weird difference between `data(1).BT_Data` and `fieldnames(data(1).BT_Data(1))`, and the tab-completion that repeatedly adds ".BT_Data".

```
>> data = stupidref;
>> data(1).BT_Data
ans = 
    BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
>> fieldnames(data(1).BT_Data)
ans = 
    'BT_Data'
>> fieldnames(data(1).BT_Data(1))
ans = 
    'foo'
    'bar'
>> length(data(1).BT_Data)
ans =
     1
>> data(1).BT_Data.BT_Data.BT_Data.BT_Data.BT_Data.BT_Data % produced by tab-completion
ans = 
    BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
>>
```

Your workaround is good - once you call `a = data(1).BT_Data`, you've got a normal struct, and the nonstandard subsref is out of the way. You can get the same effect in a one-liner with `getfield`.

```
>> btdata = getfield(data(1).BT_Data, 'BT_Data')
btdata = 
1x66 struct array with fields:
    foo
    bar
```

I would report this as a possible bug to the RWAPI library authors.

Feel free to just edit this code in to your own workaround answer; it's not really an answer so much as supporting diagnostics.

Comment: +1: Nice! Looks like you found the smoking gun. I'd love to be a fly on the wall if ever the RWAPI library authors come to this thread and see a class named "stupidref" that reproduces what their class does! =D

Comment: Wow, awesome work! It's really above my head right now (I've never used Matlab for stuff beyond arrays/matrices/etc. before), but this will be a great reference as I'm trying to understand structs/objs more. +1 indeed (I can do that now!).

Comment: Thanks guys! @Jpatton, with any luck, you'll have to deal with very little of this sort of thing in your Matlab career.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround, though it's not terribly satisfying:

> >> a = data(1).BT_Data
>
> a =
>
> ```
> BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
> ```
>
> >> length(a.BT_Data)
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 66
> ```

<strike>I'll mark this as the answer for now because I doubt there will be any other "proper" way to do it.</strike>

Andrew's answer really nailed down the issue (and why this workaround works).

Comment: This makes sense if it's an oddity in the RWAPI's subsref methods. When you do a chain of references like `data(1).BT_Data(3)`, all the steps - "(1)", ".BT_Data", and "(3)" - get passed to data's subsref() method, and it is free to handle or mishandle them how it wants. By capturing the results of a shorter reference in an intermediate variable, you get a struct, and can call normal indexing and length() functions.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your results seem contradictory. For starters, if the field `BT_Data` contained a 1-by-66 structure array, I would expect to see output like this:

```
>> data(1).BT_Data

ans =

1x66 struct array with fields:
     Flags
     ...    %# etc.
```

The fact that you see this:

```
>> data(1).BT_Data

ans =

BT_Data: [1x66 struct]
```

suggests to me that `BT_Data` is actually a 1-by-1 structure with one field called `BT_Data`, and *that* field contains a 1-by-66 structure array. This would explain what you see when you get the length and size of the first `BT_Data` (a 1-by-1 structure). If this is the case, you should get the following results:

```
>> size(data(1).BT_Data.BT_Data)

ans =

     1     66
```

However, this still doesn't explain the output you see when you do:

```
fieldnames(data(1).BT_Data(1))
```

That's throwing me off. You may want to check that `BT_Data` is actually a structure and not some other type of object that may have different indexing and display behavior by doing this:

```
isstruct(data(1).BT_Data)
```

And this should return a `1` if `BT_Data` is a structure.

Comment: `isstruct` returns 1.  I have noticed that if I type in `data(1).BT_Data.` and use tab completion, it will stick in another `BT_Data`, and will keep adding `.BT_Data`'s as long as I keep tabbing. However, it will still just return `[1 1]` for size and throw up a `Warning: unexpected field`

Comment: That almost sounds like a corrupt struct. Does this proprietary API use MEX files to work with Matlab's internal data structures?

Comment: What's the output of `whos` after you've loaded the data? And how about `builtin('isstruct', data(1).BT_Data)`? (Just in case; user-defined classes can override isstruct() to masquerade as structs, builtin() bypasses that.)

Comment: @Andrew: You might want to post your comments on jpatton's question, or include "@jpatton" in your comments so that he/she gets notified of them. As it is now, I think I'm the only one getting notifications.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on one of these SE sites, so not sure myself what the proper notification etiquette is. I'm really not sure what this API does other than convert a proprietary data formatted file to this structure (or structure-eqse) format in Matlab. It's really not well documented. I may try to get in touch with someone at the ESA (it's satellite data) to see how they've dealt with it. I posted here because I thought it might just be something to do with Matlab itself.

Comment: @gnovice @Andrew I've added some more code/output to show how this API works. The way I've use the `prod` and `data` handlers comes from example code in the API doc, I really can't say much more about them.

Comment: @jpatton: Don't worry about the notification stuff I was talking about, you didn't do anything wrong. When someone comments on your post, you get [notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) through SO. The comments Andrew left on my answer were only notifying me since there was no "@jpatton" in them, and I was just letting Andrew know because I think they contain helpful information for you.

Comment: @jpatton: Yeah. This looks like an issue in the RWAPI.product and RWAPI.dataset classes. These aren't structs (corrupt or otherwise), they're objects, and they probably override subsref and are doing non-standard indexing like gnovice suggests, and maybe mishandling "chaining". That's consistent with your workaround below, and I think the tab-completion behavior too. IMHO probably a bug in RWAPI.

Comment: @jpatton, @gnovice: Yep, got a pretty full repro using objects with a bogus subsref. Posted the code under a separate answer because it's too long for a comment.